# Reformat data frame into a single row

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I want to format my data frame into a single row.

So I have this

```
RT  200 201 202 203 204 205  
2   2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 
3   2.6 3.6 4.6 5.6 6.6 7.6  
4   2.7 3.7 4.7 5.7 6.7 7.7
```

And I want this:

```
m/z 200 201 202 203 204 205 200 201 202 203 204 205 200 201 202 203 204 205
RT  2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4
Sa  2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 2.6 3.6 4.6 5.6 6.6 7.6 2.7 3.7 4.7 5.7 6.7 7.7
```

Can anyone provide me code for this?

Note: I want to add row names "m/z" and "Sa" to the rows instead of leaving it blank.

Comment: What is `Sa`, where does it come from?

Comment: I added "Sa" and "m/z" manually. It can be anything.